# Vlookup with wild card

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Can someone help me with a question:

Im trying to find the lookup value in column A, in column B.

Column A has multiple values in it, so I have been trying to use a wild card to find it.

any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? I am getting the "NA" error even with cells that only have 1 value?

[image]

Comment: You can't use wild card to number values. Only to texts. What your actual goal? Which version of excel you are using?

Comment: Are you not trying to do this lookup the other way around? Column A has delimited values. Also, why `VLOOKUP()` if you just want to know if they exist? What is the follow-up if you found the value? Have a feeling this is an x-y problem.

Comment: Thank you, Harun24hrs & JvdV for responding. I am trying to find the list of numbers in column A, in Column B. i.e. column A has the delimited values( I know its not usual, but that is what I am trying to find) . I have Excel 365.

Answer (score 1):

To use a wildcard on numeric values, you must convert the numeric array to a text array using the `TEXT()` function.

In the example below, I've used the `INDEX-MATCH` syntax to find the item:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*" & B1 & "*",TEXT(A:A,"0"),0))
```

---

**Update from Comment**

If you have 365 then you could use the MAKEARRAY function and MATCH on that.

I've created three helper LAMBDA expressions - you would save these as a Named Range (Formula tab):

*TextItemCount*: =LAMBDA(str,sep,LEN(str)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(str,sep,""))-1)

*TextSepPos*: =LAMBDA(n,str,sep,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(str,sep,"@",n)))

and

*TextItemLen*: =LAMBDA(n,str,sep,TextSepPos(n+1,str,sep)-TextSepPos(n,str,sep)-1)

The following formula will return the row number of an item in A that is found in B:

```
=MAKEARRAY(1,TextItemCount(TextToSplit(A2,";"),";"),LAMBDA(r,c,MATCH(TRIM(MID(TextToSplit(A2,";"),TextSepPos(c,TextToSplit(A2,";"),";")+1,TextItemLen(c,TextToSplit(A2,";"),";"))),TEXT($B:$B,"0"),0)))
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you  Ambie, this is good - but it is searching the wrong way around, I am trying to find column A in Column B. I know column A has delimited numbers in it. Can you please help. I am using excel 365

Comment: @a.omz see my update